# Which integer partitions correspond to the most set partitions?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, extremal-combinatorics

Which integer partitions of n correspond to the most distinct set partitions?

For small n where it is feasible to calculate these values for every integer partition and compare, this is a straightforward exercise with the multinomial function...but beyond that range, what constraints can be put on the form of the integer partitions realizing that maximum?

For example, the five integer partitions of n=4 correspond to the block sizes of the fifteen set partitions like so:

```
4    [1234]
31   [123,4],[124,3],[134,2],[234,1]
22   [12,34],]13,24],[14,23]
211  [12,3,4],[13,2,4],[14,2,3],[23,1,4],[24,1,3],[34,1,2]
1111 [1,2,3,4]
```

Thus 211 is the integer partition yielding the most set partitions for n=4.

The optimal partition is not always unique, and its maximum part size doesn't even increase monotonically, so rather than relying on empirical guesswork I was wondering if the underlying patterns had been identified previously, perhaps under a different name.

```
    n   max set partitions           int partition
    1   1                            (1,)
    3   3                            (2, 1)
    4   6                            (2, 1, 1)
    5   15                           (2, 2, 1)
    6   60                           (3, 2, 1)
    7   210                          (3, 2, 1, 1)
    8   840                          (3, 2, 2, 1)
    9   3780                         (3, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    13  2702700                      (4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    16  756756000                    (4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    18  38594556000                  (4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    21  17110253160000               (4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    22  141159588570000              (4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    23  1298668214844000             (5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    25  108222351237000000           (4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    26  1125512452864800000          (5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    27  11395813585256100000         (5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    29  1156675078903494150000       (5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    30  15422334385379922000000      (5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
    31  159364121982259194000000     (5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
```

Equivalently, which monomial/s of the exponential Bell polynomials for a given n have the largest coefficient, as n increases?

Comment: This sequence is in https://oeis.org/A102356 which gives a citation to Knuth.  Does anyone have a copy of Knuth at hand?

Comment: You need to know how many partitions are there for every partition size and find the maximum of all of these coeficients?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Give some examples or clarify your question.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Knuth lists the difficulty as the higher end of "term project," like a student could solve it in a semester with adviser help. No answer is given, I cannot tell if Knuth knows the solution.

Comment: @MichaelLugo  Thanks, that was the first place I looked but must've been a typo in my earlier search as it turned up no entries.

Comment: @Dunkel   I'm not so interested in the coefficients themselves as I am the common qualities of the integer partitions achieving them.  Exhaustive comparison works well enough for small n, but I'd prefer to have something on more solid theoretical footing than 'well it looks kinda like the other maxima so far' when culling particular lengths, maximum part sizes, etc.

Comment: @MikeEarnest  Thanks for the lookup...sounds like I have my work cut out for me (unless it's already been resolved elsewhere...)

Comment: The values of n for which you've given examples are precisely those values (up to 31) for which the optimal partition is unique, correct?

Comment: Also, are you interested in calculation approaches which are more efficient than "*calculate these values for every integer partition and compare*" but still only applicable to small-ish $n$?

Comment: Those are the unique values, yes.  Using hill-climbing should let me match the OEIS list's values up through n=300, but doesn't come with an independent confirmation,or guarantee the maximum found is unique.

Comment: Actually found a few promising leads, but haven't made time to thoroughly digest them yet:  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316597927916 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414983900534 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000187088471022X http://www.stat.rutgers.edu/home/hcrane/Papers/STS529.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking in the comments about hill-climbing, I interpret that what you're interested is in calculating the partitions.

If we define $f(n, k)$ to be the maximum of the set partition counts over partitions of $n$ into parts of at most $k$ then we can compute it recursively: $$f(n, k) = \begin{cases}
\max_{0 \le j \le n/k} \frac{n!}{k!^j j! (n-jk)!} f(n-jk, k-1) & \textrm{if }n > 0 \\
1 & \textrm{if } k = n = 0 \\
0 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This can easily be made constructive. E.g. Python code:

```
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def binom(n, k):
    if k < 0 or k > n: return 0
    if k == 0 or k == n: return 1
    rv = 1
    for i in range(k):
        rv *= n - i
        rv //= 1 + i
    return rv


@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def biggest_partitions(n, k):
    """Each partition of n into parts of at most k corresponds to a number of set partitions. This gives the largest of those numbers."""
    if k < 0: return 0, set()
    if k == 0: return int(n == 0), set([()])

    # If we have j parts of size k, we choose jk of n to be those parts; then we have n!/(k!^j j! (n-jk!)) times most_partitions(n - jk, k - 1)
    best_score = 0
    best = set()
    lhs = 1
    for j in range(n // k + 1):
        score, examples = biggest_partitions(n - j * k, k - 1)
        score *= lhs
        if score >= best_score:
            if score > best_score:
                best = set()
            for example in examples:
                best.add(tuple([k] * j + list(example)))
            best_score = score
        lhs = lhs * binom(n - j * k, k) // (j + 1)
    return best_score, best


def A102356_explicit(n):
    if n == 0: return [()]

    best_score = 0
    best = set()
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        score, examples = biggest_partitions(n, k)
        if score >= best_score:
            if score > best_score:
                best = set()
            for example in examples:
                best.add(example)
    return sorted(best)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(A102356_explicit(300))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##vVRNk9owDD2TXyHoxYEshDLtYVt22kMPvfTU286uxyQOcT7sjG0o7Z@nUhIS2HZmp5deiGXJ0tN7Es1Pnxu9OZ8za2rIDjrxxlQOVN0Y66GyB56IJJdBEHwaDFaLk1O/5Pab0TIMUpnBTmlTMx1BGd4HE5VBCR8hBmPx8AD6Hqz0B6sh7p3b7cWLp9G9Dib2CFv6ZuhVoDRYofeStXnJOcd4uAPVWasVBsOCzD6FPb6Odb@XzvNGWK@8MtoNwGez2Rd8BYMLTIbllPamvXNkCw@1cR6xJ8Za6RqjUwcYIUAf6p20FOSkH7O4JXzPlYO9OkqMzCVUwhIGikQBnOxfuiUiGPkbaYsoIQuv2Bt8CI7p9irsoh5Z@BQGweQNfM3gh4RcHCUUI36iA8qIXEluqHhRdn1iDzvZA2rDPxBYPSTR0xUrp88FFFNg@q4op2EIXtXYFDFywyhqVGCREr9rxL0jxh0SJlHeuLPx1HdV5W5UvRhV1ygwplhgCpK/fR@BPIm6qSQ9@ZuWVBnmcFW8e0ijg4XQRBK7mwfMMACjCleul54XkCct1h4KIb6gGoOXIk2ZP@AleyyfEFKBnVTKedbHhmGb6Iab9ou3HSX0O79s11VjIRHDipaZYfTHPFF7xkWgef@8jt9u3r3n8tRUKlE4Lf2O6ttBorkJXlMqa5d2EGgdgV78iziE/T8rcCF74MnhX5tMGQXgngRYkHMtask5ETLjvBZKcz7DPI2l9fqDwU0co3Tn828).